# Arcpy - Calculate volume using CutFill tool

Tags: arcpy, volume

Currently i have the output of Pix4D which contains: DSM, DTM, LAS file. I want to calculate the volume of a polygon specified by coordinate.
Here is the script i'm using right now:

```
        arcpy.FeatureToRaster_conversion(Polygon_Layer, "FID", poly_mask, Cellsize)

        #Convert Poly verticies to points, extract raster value to poly points, convert poly to raster
        poly_boundaries = "p_boundaries.shp"
        arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management(Polygon_Layer, poly_boundaries, "ALL")
        #arcpy.AddMessage("Extracting elevation values from elevation raster...")
        poly_boundaries_elevation = "p_boundaries_elevation.shp"
        ExtractValuesToPoints(poly_boundaries, Elevation_Raster, poly_boundaries_elevation, "NONE", "VALUE_ONLY")

        #converts raster with elevation points to a TIN. 
        tin_parameter = poly_boundaries_elevation + " RASTERVALU masspoints"
        poly_tin = "poly_tin"
        arcpy.CreateTin_3d(poly_tin, sr, tin_parameter, "DELAUNAY")

        #Tin to raster
        TinRastCellSize = "CELLSIZE " + Cellsize
        cap_raster = "cap_raster"
        arcpy.TinRaster_3d(poly_tin, cap_raster, "FLOAT", "", TinRastCellSize, "")

        #calculates volume above raster, adds output to the poly shp
        outCutFill = CutFill(clipped_raster, cap_raster, 1)
        temporary_cut_fill = "cutfill.tif"
        outCutFill.save(temporary_cut_fill)
```

The raster i used in this script is DSM.
I use DroneDeploy.com to recheck my result, but the problem is that:

- If my polygon contains small feature such as: hole, building then my result is quite similar to DroneDeploy
- But if my polygon is big and contains buiding, tree, hole etc then just Fill volume is correct and Cut volume is not similar to DroneDeploy result.

I have tried to changed to using DTM but the result is not correct. Can you guys show me what's wrong with my script?